# Masking Sub-domain with primary domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, subdomain, shopify

I'm not sure if this possible but here goes.

So I have a bunch of sites which accessed via different sub domains. Each sub domain is created to serve Geo-located users. However, we do not want to the sub domains to be customer facing as they are not desirable and we believe all customers should access from the same one url point.

Therefore we desire that all traffic is ran through and masked by the primary either through an htaccess or a web app. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you placed the **tag** Shopify in your answer, the short answer there is, Shopify already geo-locates your customers to the fastest server for their location. You cannot do that yourself, or, in other words, they probably do it better than you could anyway.

If you don't mean Shopify, then your question is one of DNS and co-location of server boxes around the world, a topic pretty heavy for one answer here.

Comment: It would be using Shopify. However the limitation of running multiple store instances is that you have to use different sub domains per store. Therefore we would like to look into the possibility to run everything through one customer facing domain without visibly facing sub domains.

Comment: Perhaps I am mis-understanding. Shopify does not want you to run multiple instances of your Shop. You run ONE. They take care of ensuring it is fast for customers in their region. If I am wrong, and Shopify insists you run multiple instances, that defeats the purpose of their world-wide CDN and geo-location internally does it not?

Comment: With shopify plus you have the ability to create multiple stores under one brand. An example of why this would be done could be you have different pricing in different regions based on market positioning. Therefore Shopify only supports FX rate pricing variations and not market differing price books. The solution to this problem is to create multiple stores which are link to one brand and are accessed via  sub domains. However, as a brand we do not want our sub domains visible to the user for each of the regions especially if it is not country/ language driven but instead price.

Comment: Sure sure... I get that. So make N shops with Shopify. Setup the DNS so you control the main shop. Send requests to your own server using DNS. Now use your internal logic to simply relay to the appropriate Shopify domain. Should not pose any trouble for you since this is basic DNS work with your own geo-location code helping.